# Origen remotes and HTTP files

Tags: origen-sdk

We use [remotes](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/remotes/) extensively and the request came about how Origen handles straight links to HTTP files versus revision control systems. Can Origen remotes just put an HTTP link as the vault?

```
Origen.config.remotes do
  [
    {
      dir: "mydir",
      vault: "http://mycompany/fileserver/myspreadsheet.xlsx"
    }
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but should not be too difficult for you to add.

The remotes system uses the [Origen revision control API](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/revisioncontrol/) under the hood and passes the given `rc_url:` (or `vault:` as in this example, which is an alias) option to the revision control API to deal with - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/remote_manager.rb#L140

So, if you were to add an http(s) revision control driver to Origen, then http remote urls should work - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/revision_control.rb

Note that for such an http revision control driver, you would not need to support all the API (commit, etc), just the `remotes_method` which is defined as `checkout` by default, but could actually be anything you like, e.g. `get` might be more appropriate for a fetch over http - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/921248e1e8514f28284ff7fca74f9ccf2243d061/lib/origen/revision_control/base.rb#L32